# Python SQLAlchemy pass multiple tuples in parameters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Trying to pass multiple tuples in SQLAlchemy Query. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
salesforce_query = "SELECT t1.[CaseNumber] as [SR_Number], t6.name as [SR_Type], case when t1.Status = 'Internal Departments' then 'Int. Departments' else t1.Status end as [SR_Status], \
                        t1.IsEscalated as [Escalation_Indicator], format(t1.[CreatedDate], 'M/d/yyyy') AS [SR_Open_Date], format(t1.[ClosedDate], 'M/d/yyyy') as [SR_Close_Date], \
                        t5.Name as [SR_Owner], t2.Name as [Policy], isnull(t2.BDS_Broker_Firm__c,'') as [BDS_Firm], isnull(t2.BDS_Broker_Location_Token_ID__c,0) as [BDS_Location_ID], isnull(t2.BDS_Broker_Location__c,'') as [BDS_Location]  \
                        FROM [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Case] t1 inner JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Policy__c] t2 ON t1.[Policy__c] = t2.[Id] \
                        inner JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Account] t3 ON t2.[Office__c] = t3.[Id] inner JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Contact] t4 ON t1.[Broker_of_Record__c] = t4.[Id] \
                        inner JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[User] t5 ON t1.[OwnerId] = t5.[Id] inner JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[RecordType] t6 ON t1.[RecordTypeId] = t6.[Id] \
                        WHERE t2.BDS_Broker_Location_Token_ID__C in {bdsstring1} AND t5.[Profile__c] in ('Customer Loyalty Manager', 'Client Relationship Executive') and t1.CreatedDate >= '" + start_date + "' \
                        or t1.ClosedDate >= '" + start_date + "' and t2.BDS_Broker_Location_Token_ID__C in {bdsstring} AND t5.[Profile__c] in ('Customer Loyalty Manager', 'Client Relationship Executive')".format(bdsstring1=tuple(bds_string),bdsstring=tuple(bds_string))
```

Trying to use multiple tuples for parameters since the values in the tuples originate from another database that is not connected.

Comment: Please don't use string manipulation to generate queries. Besides being potentially unsafe, it leads to bugs for all but the simplest queries. I suspect that your problem will be solved through the process of refactoring this code to use [bound parameters](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute.params.parameters).